# hide notification bar in fullscreen app which have spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I run an app in fullscreen mode where fullscreen is defined as a theme in xml for the entire app.

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

i have a spinner in my app,the dropdown list of spinner have many items and have scroller,so when pop the spinner,the notification is show,and then hide when i choice one item as pic http://www.mathiaslin.com/dl/statusbar2.png, i have read 
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3674,but iam a spinner not a dialog so i cannot use

```
dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN    

    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

can you help me?